# Metro bundler Error When I run expo start

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler

I am working on a react native expo project. I was running expo start with no problem until I updated my MacBook. Now, I am facing this error:

Could not get status from Metro bundler. Connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19003
Connecting to Metro bundler failed.

My expo diagnostics is as below:

> Expo CLI 3.22.3 environment info:
> System:
> OS: macOS 10.15.5
> Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
> Binaries:
> Node: 12.18.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
> npm: 6.14.6 - /usr/local/bin/npm
> IDEs:
> Android Studio: 3.6 AI-192.7142.36.36.6200805
> Xcode: 11.6/11E708 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
> npmPackages:
> expo: ^38.0.0 => 38.0.8
> react: 16.11.0 => 16.11.0
> react-dom: 16.11.0 => 16.11.0
> react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz =>
> 0.62.2
> react-native-web: ~0.11.7 => 0.11.7
> npmGlobalPackages:
> expo-cli: 3.22.3

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, according to [this](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/949) github page, you can:

1. Restart your computer
2. Run `rm -rf .expo`

Instead, according to [Expo forum](https://forums.expo.io/t/can-t-connect-to-metro-bundler/32691/7) you can try to launch expo start with -c like `expo start -c`

Comment: Thanks for your respond, but I have already done these and still no success

Comment: Ok lets start to investigate. Have you tried expo start --tunnel or expo start --lan?

Comment: Yes I did, I also removed the node folder and ran expo install.

Comment: Ok, lets try to reinstall expo-cli: $ npm uninstall -g expo-cli
$ npm cache clean --force
$ npm install -g expo-cli

Comment: Hi Giovanni, Thanks for your comment, I tried what you suggested and still I am getting the same error. I deleted all the metro folders from node_modules and ran sudo expo install again, it worked once but again I am facing Metro bundler Error.

Comment: At this point, I start to think that could be only a problem between node and expo-cli version. Lets try to downgrade expo-cli to 3.1.2 version: npm install -g expo-cli@3.1.2

Comment: Thank you so much Giovanni, I downgraded the node.js and now it is fixed. Thanks for your help

Comment: very well!! If you want, tell me expo-cli and node versions that solve your problme so I can update my answer. Ciao :)